# Auto generated email delivery delay?

Tags: email, hosting, web-hosting

I used mailing in one of my site, It will work finely and it will deliver the receiver  email very fast in our development server. When i transfer all the file to the original live server it will take very delay to deliver the mail the original server in network solution. How can i solve this it is very important in the site.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on may three reason,

1.Your server downtime.

2.The email for which you are sending doesn't exist.

3.The dns of the email for which you are sending your mail may have down time.